# return multiple values in desire format with mapping in node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, mapping, nodes

```js
const parsers = new Map();

parsers._get = parsers.get;
parsers.get = function (key) {
  if (this.has(key)) return this._get(key);
  return () =>
    console.warn(`Parser not implemented for: ${JSON.stringify(key)}`);
};

parsers.set("document", parseDocument);
parsers.set("paragraph", parseParagraph);
parsers.set("text", parseText);
parsers.set("table", parseTable);
parsers.set("tablerow", parseRow);
parsers.set("tr", parseTR);
parsers.set("tablehc", parseHC);
parsers.set("tablec", parseTableC);

function convert(obj) {
  return [parsers.get(obj.nodeType)(obj)];
}

function parseDocument(obj) {
  let type = "doc";
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  return { type, children };
}

function parseParagraph(obj) {
  let type = "p";
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  return { type, children };
}

function parseText(obj) {
  const result = {};
  result.text = obj.value;
  obj.marks.forEach((e) => (result[e.type] = true));
  return result;
}

function parseTable(obj) {
  let type = "table";
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => {
    children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e));
  });
  children = children
    .map((c) => {
      return c;
    })
    .flat();
  return { type, children };
}

function parseRow(obj) {
  var type = [];
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.nodeType === "tablehc") {
      type.push("thead");
      children.push(parsers.get("tr")(e));
    } else {
      parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e);
      type.push("tbody");
      children.push(parsers.get("tr")(e));
    }
  });
  type = [...new Set(type)].join();
  return { type, children };
}

function parseTR(obj) {
  let type = "tr";
  let children = [];
  children.push(parsers.get(obj.nodeType)(obj));
  children = children
    .map((c) => {
      return c;
    })
    .flat();
  return { type, children };
}

function parseHC(obj) {
  let type = "th";
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  children = children
    .map((c) => {
      return c;
    })
    .flat();
  return { type, children };
}

function parseTableC(obj) {
  let type = "td";
  let children = [];
  obj.content.forEach((e) => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  children = children
    .map((c) => {
      return c;
    })
    .flat();
  return { type, children };
}

let result = convert(getSrcData());
console.log("Converted object: ", result);

function getSrcData() {
  return {
    nodeType: "document",
    content: [
      {
        nodeType: "paragraph",
        content: [
          {
            nodeType: "text",
            value: "dummy testing bold",
            marks: [
              {
                type: "bold",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        nodeType: "table",
        content: [
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablehc",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "hey",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                nodeType: "tablehc",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "code text",
                        marks: [
                          {
                            type: "code",
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "text",
                        marks: [
                          {
                            type: "bold",
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        nodeType: "paragraph",
        content: [
          {
            nodeType: "text",
            value: "",
            marks: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        nodeType: "table",
        content: [
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablehc",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "hey",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                nodeType: "tablehc",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                nodeType: "tablehc",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "code text",
                        marks: [
                          {
                            type: "code",
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            nodeType: "tablerow",
            content: [
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "bold text",
                        marks: [
                          {
                            type: "bold",
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                nodeType: "tablec",
                content: [
                  {
                    nodeType: "paragraph",
                    content: [
                      {
                        nodeType: "text",
                        value: "",
                        marks: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

I wrote this code and I am getting the expected output for all the parsers which I have passed in my code. Here I have provided the minimal code that I am trying to achieve. As I want to fetch the table data from the getSrcData function as my expected output is like this.

I am trying to get the table converted data into this expected format when I am trying to parse all the output but it is not helping me as it is showing me in the above result is there any way I can get the expected output by using this code as all the other conditions are working as expected in my code but only the table output is not matching the desire expectation. Like I want all the head parts in one place and all the body parts in one place.

expected output:-

```
Converted object: [
  {
    "type": "doc",
    "children": [
      {
        "type": "p",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "dummy testing bold",
            "bold": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "table",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "head",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "th",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "hey" }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "body",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "code text", "code": true }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "bold text", "bold": true }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "p",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },

// table should look like this
      {
        "type": "table",
        "children": [
          {
// head part contains only the head part and its supporting children
            "type": "head",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "th",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "hey" }]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "th",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "" }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
// body part contains only the body part and its supporting children
          {
            "type": "body",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "code text", "code": true }]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "" }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "tr",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "bold text", "bold": true }]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "td",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "p",
                        "children": [{ "text": "" }]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```